# Travis CI: Karma testing passing but always get errored build

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, travis-ci

I've been trying yo integrate travis for CI in my free-source project.
When I push to my repository, all looks ok , but after execute `karma start --single-run`, the console of the travis don't stop to execute the karma start task.

How to fix this?

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
sudo: false
node_js:
  - 0.10
script: karma start -–single-run
before_install:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
before_script:
  - npm install -g bower 
  - npm install
  - bower install
```

Travis Console
[image: Errored build]

**Updated Question** : 
Why in the travis process when i use in the console `karma start --single-run` the option no overwrite the option singleRun: false in the karma.conf.js? In my local environment this works fine.

Comment: Karma might be waiting for user input, which it can't get

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь I don't understand why karma be waiting for user input. the `--single-run` works fine in my local machine

Comment: That looks like it's the case, no idea why it'd happen otherwise

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь Finally I solve this, check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved, the problem was in my `karma.conf.js`

```
singleRun: true,
```

I change this option from false to true. Frequently when i develop, use singleRun option in my karma configuration file to false for use auto watch option.
The weird thing it's that in my local machine when i run karma with the option explicity in the command line (`karma start --single-run`), the option in the `karma.conf.js` is overwritten, but in travis this it's not posible.